# matrices with all maximal minors non-singular

Tags: linear-algebra

I encountered a sequence of matrices whose maximal minors seem to be all non-singular.

In other words, suppose that we have an $m\times n$ matrix with $m \leq n$, then any choice of $m$ columns is linearly independent.

Has this property been studied before?  Does it have a name?  Are there any stronger properties which might be easier to prove?

Update: in fact, it seems that *all* minors are non-zero.

Comment: A stronger property is that all maximal minors are positive. Then this condition has come up in the context of the totally positive Grassmannian. In particular, see Lemma 3.9 of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609764

Comment: @SamHopkins, thank you!  Unfortunately, this is not the case.  To make sure: there is in fact no ordering of the columns such that the matrix is totally positive.

Comment: Even if your matrix is not totally positive, if you want to use some fancy language you can still say the following: it represents a point in the "big cell" of the matroid stratification of the Grassmannian.

Comment: One more comment: having all minors non-zero may seem like a special property, but of course in a technical sense it is a *generic* property. That may be why you are having trouble finding where it is studied.